# Gimp Preferences/Folders shows no script folder

Tags: directory, preferences, gimp

Gimp 2.10.36 on Windows 11.  Edit/Preferences/Folders shows only a Swap folder and a Temp folder, no Scripts or Plug-ins folder.  I don't know where to put my .py script.

I expected to find more folders there than the two I have no interest in.  Do they appear elsewhere?  Do I have to create the folder?